# How mongoose populate more than 2 level deep?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I define the comment model as:

```
CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    website: String,
    content: String,
    createDate: Date,
    updateDate: Date,
    targetBlog: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blog'},
    childrenComment: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
});
```

And when I use populate as:

```
Comment.find({targetBlog: blog._id}).populate({path: 'childrenComment'}).exec(function(err, comments) {
    console.log(comments);
    res.render('blog', { blog: blog, comments: comments});
});
```

I find mongoose only populate one level deep. So how can I do to make it populate more than one level, because the level can be 2 or 3 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the model manually when populating.

```
Comment.find({targetBlog: blog._id})
    .populate({path: 'childrenComment', model: 'Comment'})
        .exec(function(err, comments) {
            console.log(comments);
            res.render('blog', { blog: blog, comments: comments});
});
```

**Update:**

It looks like your code is working without adding the model. So the problem should be somewhere else, not in the populating. This is what you are trying to do, right?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `Comment.find({targetBlog: blog._id})` returns a `Comment` from the database?

Comment: Are you sure that adding `model: 'Comment'` will help mongoose to populate more than one level deep?

Comment: Yes, I have used this recently.